# Margin collapsing, css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have the header in fixed position.(Header staying fixed in top position and the content goes below)
as soon as i put the position fixed the bottom margin collapses.

Any easy fix? I been trying to use clearfix, clear:both ect..

http://libra-frisk.com/gadjos/

Comment: What do you mean "the bottom margin collapsing"? Can you post a screenshot of the issue or a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: For reasons why your question may be closed, please see: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/159834)

Answer (score 2):

fixed positioned elements are outside of the flow of the typical box-model

you can add a margin-top on the content underneath or a padding top on the `body`

Answer (score 0):

You could make it absolute position. I'm not sure if that helps because your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the header to remain fixed, then add this:

```
#sliderHolder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 312px;
    margin-top: 158px;
}
```

You don't need `clear:both` since that's for floats.

Answer (score 0):

If you want get something that:
[image: screen]
You should use change rule for sliderHolder to this:

```
#sliderHolder {
    margin-top: 158px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 312px;
}
```